# Какой алгоритм поиска подстроки (из множества подстрок) в строке выбрать?

Tags: python, алгоритм, поиск

Есть список подстрок (пусть несколько тысяч). Есть список строк (несколько сот тысяч). Необходимо найти все соответствия подстрокам в первом списке. Решение 'в лоб' не годится, там получается значительное количество итераций, как минимум O(n³):

```
substring_list = ['one', 'two', ..., 'one thousand']
data_list = ['one spam', 'two ham', ..., 'one billion jam']
out_list = []
for item in data_list:
    for s in substring_list:
       if s in item:
           out_list.append(item)
```

Какой способ лучший способ, для решения этой задачи?

Comment: Недостаточно информации в плане условий для сравнения. Учитываются ошибки, опечатки или теоретически все верно, просто надо сравнить ?
Если просто сравнить, то выбирай ответ про Рабина-Карпа, он будет идеален, лишь добавлю что кэш слов, лучше добавить куданить в таблицу и к ней запрос на условие in по кэшу, при этом закэшировав искомые строки. Тогда будет намного быстрее и без итераций :)
А если поиск с учетом ошибок, то перебор прийдется делать и кэш не поможет.

Comment: @IvanZakirov: Рабин-Карп не умеет искать несколько подстрок одновременно => общее время пробега пропорционально размеру списка подстрок, т. к. приходится искать одну за одной.

Comment: @IvanZakirov: Будем считать,что ошибки не учитываются, нужно просто сравнить, входит ли substring в string или нет.

Comment: @VladD я же написал что по Карпу, но дополнительно засунуть в базу и запрос сделать IN, что ускорит и уберет итерации. А вообще можно и без КЭША, просто засунуть в базу и like '%...%'
А вот Aho–Corasick метод.. ну я думаю он больше подходит для языков как Prolog и составления семантических сетей, нежели Python.

Так что перебор )))

Comment: Я подобную задачу решал путем разбивания искомого текста, на слова, и сравниваемого текста на слова, и путем запроса брал количество совпавших слов, если 100% значит совпало :) ну и т.д... Запрос убирал все итерации кроме что разве пройтись по списку с которым сравниваем. Учитывая что строки разные и это не один текст а несколько, то там надо просто создать верные отношения и сравнить их сразу все. Но.. у меня была специфичная задачка.. тут может и не такой подход нужен... Попробуйте через регулярные выражения, если такое есть в питоне. Во многих языках они прекрасно работают с массивами.

Comment: @IvanZakirov: Вы серьёзно считаете, что использование базы данных **ускорит** поиск?

Comment: @VladD серьезно предполагаю что основные способы поиска информации ведутся по базам данных. В том числе и путем применения регулярных выражениях встроенных в БД (ну если такие есть). Но не настаиваю на этом. Просто как вариант. И да, это делается быстро. Если вы думаете что реализовав тут алгоритм Ахо-Корасик будет идти быстрее.. ну... значит быстрее.

Comment: @IvanZakirov Работа с базой не входит в задачу. Я пишу утилиту для разбора логов,

Comment: @IvanZakirov: База данных — это либо IPC, либо даже чтение с диска. Оно не может быть скорее, чем поиск в памяти. А алгоритмы база данных использует те же, что и любой человек может.

Comment: А поиск при помощи питона - обязательное условие? Может быть имеет смысл воспользоваться стандартными средствами linux? Недавно вопрос был (сейчас не помню какой именно) - там тоже надо было искать строки по большому набору данных. Вроде как даже тов. @VladD советовал `grep -F` (или `fgrep`). Т.е. можно сначала получить все совпадения через `grep`, а потом уже обрабатывать их как вам надо

Comment: @ВОРОН Python условие не обязательное, но желательное. Буду пробовать разные варианты, проверять по скорости.

Comment: @VladD увы, но вы не знаете базы данных. Они выбирают данные с огромной скоростью из таких объемов, что ваша ОЗУ не вместит.
Читайте внимательнее "Есть список подстрок (пусть несколько тысяч). Есть список строк (несколько сот тысяч)." - не думаю что при увеличении объемов и даже этот объем он хранит в ОЗУ...

Comment: @IvanZakirov: Давайте подумаем головой. База данных для поиска использует не секретные заклинания, а те же алгоритмы, что можете реализовать и вы, и я. Так что для случая базы in-memory, in-process база обеспечит такую же производительность. А если база бежит вне вашего процесса, то существенно хуже. Понятно, почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, вам нужен [алгоритм Ахо-Корасик](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm). Он применяется для эффективного поиска **набора** подстрок.

Comment: Если входные данные на диске лежат, то `grep -F -f substring_list data_list` можно использовать (алгоритм тот же).

Comment: @jfs, судя по "Я пишу утилиту для разбора логов" они там и лежат.

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать воспользоваться алгоритмом Рабина-Карпа поиска подстроки в строке.

Пусть есть подстрока `sub` длины `m` и строка `s` длины `n`, в которой мы ищем подстроку.

1. Для начала вычислим хэш от подстроки `sub`
2. В строке `s` для каждой подстроки, длины `m`, вычислим её хэш. Если хэш этой подстроки и строки `sub` совпадают, то, потенциально, мы нашли вхождение подстроки `sub` в строку `s`.
3. Проверим, что вхождение действительно имеет место быть, вручную сравнив строку `sub` и подстроку строки `s`, с которой совпал хэш.

Аппроксимированно такой поиск будет требовать `O(n + m)` времени, в худшем случае до `O(n*m)`.

Для того, чтобы быстро пересчитывать хеш в строке `s` используется кольцевой хэш, который позволяет быстро вычислить значение `hash(s[1:m+1])`, зная значение `hash(s[0:m])`. Вычисляется он по следующему принципу:

```
hash(s[0:m]) = p**(m-1) * ord(s[0]) + 
               p**(m-2) * ord(s[1]) + 
               ... + 
               p * ord(s[m-2]) + 
               ord(s[m-1])
```

И для того, чтобы получить из этого хэша значение для `s[1:m+1]`, достаточно выполнить следующие действия:

```
hash(s[1:m+1]) = hash(s[0:m]) * p - p**m * ord(s[0]) + ord(s[m])
```

что выполняется за константное время.

Требуется только выбрать нужное значение `p`, рекомендуется обычно взять относительно большое простое число, например, 1000000007. Также стоит заранее посчитать и запомнить степени числа `p` до `p**m`.

Так как в этой задаче много подстрок, то если среди них есть строки совпадающей длины, можно воспользоваться уже вычисленными ранее значениями хэшей, т.е. если строка `sub1` и строка `sub2` имеют одинаковые длины, то для строки `sub2` можно будет воспользоваться вычисленными хэшами строки `s` для `sub1`.

Для меньшего числа коллизий можно выбрать несколько значений `p` и считать хэши для каждого из них, таким образом, необходимость проверять коллизию будет возникать реже, только если для всех `p` значение хэша совпало.

Comment: @Timoey Bondarev  Насколько реализация этого алгоритма именно на Python будет быстрее, чем простой перебор?

Comment: @to_night На большом наборе строк должно быть достаточно заметное ускорение работы, но оно может зависеть также от способа реализации самого алгоритма и применяемых оптимизаций. Ожидаемое количество коллизий в среднем не так велико, чтобы сильно замедлить работу. Сам я, к сожалению, не сравнивал скорости работ этих подходов, чтобы ответить более обоснованно.

Answer (score 1):

Если строки уникальны и ни одна из них не является подстрокой другой (из того же множества), то полный перебор неизбежен, но если некоторые являются подстроками других, то поиск можно оптимизировать, проверяя сначала минимальные подстроки, и если они найдены, проверять уже и более длинные строки, содержащие их.