# Сравнение двух строк c++

Tags: c++

Допустим у меня есть список фамилий. Мне нужно сделать поиск фамилий по нескольким первым буквам и вывести ее на экран.

Comment: Go to http://freelance.com/ !
Или покажи где проблема.

Comment: Вот [ещё по теме](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/415233/10105).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно пройти по списку и выделить строки, начинающиеся второй строкой.
Таким образом, задача сводится, фактически, к проверке, является ли одна строка префиксом другой.

Проверить, является ли одна строка префиксом другой можно многими способами.

Простейший, собственно средствами самого `std::string`:

```
X.find(Y) == 0
// что фактически означает std::string(X).find(Y) == 0
```

Самодельный:

```
bool isPrefix(string const& s1, string const&s2)
{
    const char*p = s1.c_str();
    const char*q = s2.c_str();
    while (*p&&*q)
        if (*p++!=*q++)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

С помощью `std::mismatch`:

```
std::string s1("foo");
std::string s2("foobar");

auto res = std::mismatch(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin());

if (res.first == s1.end())
{
  // s1 префикс s2
}
```

С помощью `string::compare`:

```
bool match = (0==s1.compare(
        0, min(s1.length(), s2.length()), 
    s2, 0, min(s1.length(), s2.length())));
```

Если поиск по списку выполняется регулярно,
есть смысл реорганизовать его в некую структуру данных, позволяющую выполнять поиск более эффективно.

Наиболее подходящей для решения данной задачи было бы префиксное дерево (trie).

[image: Пример префискного дерева для слов: "A", "to", "tea", "ted", "ten", "i", "in", and "inn", Источник: Wikipedia]

*Рис.1. Пример префискного дерева для слов: "A", "to", "tea", "ted", "ten", "i", "in", and "inn", Источник: Wikipedia*

Поиск по префиксному дереву будет намного эффективнее: в нормальном случае O(1), в худшем O(N).

- [Префиксное дерево](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) (рус), Википедия
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie (англ.)

Естественно, прибегать к помощи сложных структур данных имеет смысл только того, когда это оправдано. В простейшием случае достаточно будет простейшей прохода по списку и проверки строк на префиксы.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться!

Comment: `std::string(x)` в первом фрагменте кода не нужно, т. к. C++-строки и есть `std::string`.

Comment: @VladD: Влад, верно, я просто хотел подчеркнуть факт использования `std::string`, сейчас распишу детальнее

Comment: `std::string(X).find(Y)` сам по себе не говорит, что явялется префиксом. Нужно сравнить с нулём.

Comment: @ixSci: fixed! Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

Наиболее простая проверка является ли строка "hello" началом строки str:

```
if (str.find("hello") == 0)
```

Comment: Только очень неэффективная, поскольку `.find()` ищет вхождение по всей строке.